# Truncate a Shapefile field with SQL and ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr2ogr, fields-attributes, sqlite

I want to create a new attribute which is the first 8 characters of another, using ogr2ogr. To my surprise, this didn't work:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" a.shp b.shp -sql "select FID,left(FLOORKEY,8) AS BLDGKEY,*"
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected LEFT. Occured around :
select FID,left(FLOORKEY,8) AS BLDGKEY,*
           ^
```

Choosing the sqlite dialect didn't help either:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" a.shp b.shp -dialect SQLITE -sql "select FID,left(FLOORKEY,8) AS BLDGKEY,*"
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare(select FID,left(FLOORKEY,8) AS BLDGKEY,*):
  near "(": syntax error
```

What am I missing? It's GDAL 1.11.0, released 2014/04/16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GDAL SQL dialect is a subset of select SQL ([source](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html)). It looks like `left` isn't part of those functions implemented. Neither is it implemented in the sqlite [core functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Instead try the sqlite `substr(X, Y, Z)` function (credit to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10413140/379566) answer). Your query would become:

```sql
select FID, substr(FLOORKEY, 0, 8) AS BLDGKEY,* from b
```

And the dialect should remain `SQLITE`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had actually tried `SUBSTR`, but not in the right combination with `-dialect`.